# Fire event maximum once every x seconds

Tags: javascript

I have this event which is fired once every 2 seconds by external processes (it's a serial port receiving data):

```
sp.on("data", function (rawData) {
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(rawData);
        var collection = db.get('sensorsCollection');
        collection.insert({
            ...
        });
    } catch (error) {
        debug(error);
    }
});
```

But I want to store data in database only once every, let's say 500 seconds to avoid overloading my database. How to achieve that?

(Note : I tried to use `underscore.js`'s function `throttle` but couldn't find how to pass argument to the function called in `throttle` so I couldn't pass my fresh `data` variable containing most recent data.)

Comment: set a global variable to hold the current time, then add 500 seconds to it, and have your request check to see if the time is greater than it yet, then when it is add another 500 seconds to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your datas, and  send them every 500 seconds:

```
var my_datas=[];
sp.on("data", function (rawData){
    try {
      //store the data 
      my_datas.push(rawData);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        debug(error);
    }
});

setInterval(function(){
   for(var i=0, len= my_datas.length; i<len; i++){

        data = JSON.parse(my_datas[i]);
        var collection = db.get('sensorsCollection');
        collection.insert({
            ...
        });

   }
  },500*1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Totally untested, but would something like this do what you want?:

```
(function() {
    var collection = db.get('sensorsCollection');
    var data = [];

    sp.on("data", function (rawData) {
        try {
            data.push(JSON.parse(rawData));
        } catch (error) {
            debug(error);
        }
    });
    
    setInterval(function() { // try-catch here too if necessary
        collection.insert(data);  // additional formatting?
        data = [];
    }, 500 * 1000);
}());
```

**Edited** to use `setTimeout` rather than `throttle`, which didn't make sense the way it was being used.